# Need Help Understanding a Crude Benchmark: Regular PHP vs HHVM vs Zephir

Tags: php, hhvm, zephir

I performed this test using a simple factorial function (borrowed the logic from http://avelino.xxx/2014/03/golang-c-and-python-the-benchmark-time)

**Regular PHP Code**

```
function fact($n){ 
    if($n===0)return 1;
    return $n*fact($n-1);
}

function calc(){
    $t = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<8; $j++){
            $t += fact($j);
        }
    }
    return $t; 
}

$result = calc();
echo $result."\n";
```

**PHP Using Zephir**

```
$fact = new Utils\Fact();
$result = $fact->calc();
echo $result."\n";
```

**Zephir Code**

```
namespace Utils;

class Fact{
    public function fact(int n) -> int{
        if(n==0){
            return 1;
        }

        return n*this->fact(n - 1);
    }

    public function calc() -> int{
        int i,j,total;
        let total = 0;
        for i in range(0,99999){
            for j in range (0,7){
                let total = total + this->fact(j);
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

I executed these snippets using the time command in the following manner:

**Regular PHP**

```
time php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini regular.php
```

*Result*

```
591400000
real 0m0.788s
user 0m0.736s
sys 0m0.026s
```

**PHP Using Zephir Class**

```
time php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini zephyr.php
```

*Result*

```
591400000
real 0m1.529s
user 0m1.494s
sys 0m0.024s
```

**HHVM**

```
time hhvm regular.php
```

*Result*

```
591400000
real 0m0.883s
user 0m0.814s
sys 0m0.045s
```

### Question:

As you can see from the results above, regular PHP code seems to have performed better than the one that uses a compiled Zephyr class as a PHP extension. This is what has me confused.

How can the scripted code end up being faster than the compiled one, especially when both employ the same logic? I think I'm missing something here and would be grateful if someone could help me understand this.

EDIT:
Looks like others are facing a similar problem with Zephir: [Zephir 2x slower](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/issues/228)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about zephyr but HHVM is a JIT so you pay extra startup cost so that future runs are faster. Try increasing your benchmark so it takes 1 minute or 10 minutes if you want to really see HHVM perform.

Also, in some situations we decide to not turn on the JIT in command line mode so force it on with -vEval.Jit=true

Comment: I just tested this out and you're right. When I increased the run time , HHVM did perform better (4 sec faster than regular PHP over a 1 minute 30 sec run). However, a similar test for the Zephir code came out almost 2 minutes slower!

Comment: HHVM should be 10x faster than zend. What does your config look like? Try running with `hhvm -vEval.Jit=1 foo.php`

Comment: That did the trick. Zend took **73.3 seconds** while HHVM took **3.1 seconds**. (I put the call to the `calc` function in a loop for 100 times)

Comment: You are the inspiriation for https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/190a12a7a5c8b79a16182107afad5ecc7971b303

Comment: Wow! This would certainly help first timers see the benefits of HHVM right away without any additional config :)

Comment: @Jay - so the benefit of HHVM is to gloat how fast it computes factorials compared to PHP or am I missing something?

Comment: @N.B. the benefit for us is to run facebook.com 10x faster than php5 saving us a bajillion dollars per year. In open-sourcing it we hope it does the same for everyone else.

Comment: @N.B. - I posted this in the hope that someone could help me understand things better and Paul helped me understand part of it. How is any of this the equivalent of gloating?